# Trade failed but lost ether

Tags: transactions

The following transaction failed but I still lost ether also fee was charged

trx :0xa4620f966b385c68eabb19e94e286bd21c934c7b194de6d60faba3a4ea3e680e

Thanks
Bravocc

Comment: if the tx fails (which that one did), then the transaction is reverted. the only ether you lost from that tx was the fee.

Answer (score 1):

You can check the status here https://etherscan.io/tx/0xa4620f966b385c68eabb19e94e286bd21c934c7b194de6d60faba3a4ea3e680e

It seems your transction was executed but an exception led to the transaction failing. Gas price is not refunded in case of failed transactions (0.001 Ether was applied). You should not loose any of transaction ether though.

Comment: I lost my ether too , i can understand gas fee but i lost ether too. Here is the trade https://deltabalances.github.io/tx.html#0xa4620f966b385c68eabb19e94e286bd21c934c7b194de6d60faba3a4ea3e680e

Comment: Based on your origin wallet you have not lost any ether on the transaction.  https://etherscan.io/address/0x3af0cbc4ead5a8828fbdf67f40223379b3c052a8

The link you shared shows the ETH value as 0. It seems the input indicates what you intended to do. Have you verified your wallet balance to be sure that ETH was deducted?